# Transmission test port

Tags: transmission, torrent-client

I changed downloading port in `transmission` from random one to port `80`. Then I tried to test it and got a result that port is closed.

[image]

How can I open it for downloading?

Answer (score 0):

You do that on your router: it is called Port Forwarding. Unfortunately how to do that is different on every router (well the actual port forwarding tab will look the same but how you get there differs).

Regarding transmission also have a look at their [FAQ](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/wiki/Why-is-my-port-closed%3F).